# CakePHP Multidimensional Model - Joining in wrong place

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm having an issue with Cake joining tables in the wrong place :(

I have three tables - `CC_PLAYLIST`, `CC_PLAYLISTCONTENTS`, and `CC_FILES`.

I'd like to get a list of all playlists, with all of their contents, and then the relevant file information for each piece of playlist content.

I.E

```
Playlist 1
-- Playlist Content 1
---- File Info
-- Playlist Content 2
---- File Info
-- Playlist Content 3
---- File Info
Playlist 2
-- Playlist Content 123
---- File Info
```

In my Model (AirtimePlaylist) I get this data with

```
$result = $this->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'AirtimePlaylistContent' => array(
            'fields' => array('AirtimePlaylistContent.id', 'AirtimePlaylistContent.playlist_id', 'AirtimePlaylistContent.file_id'),
            'AirtimeFile' => array(
                'fields' => array('AirtimeFile.id', 'AirtimeFile.track_title', 'AirtimeFile.artist_name')
            )
        ),
    ),
    'conditions' => array('AirtimePlaylist.id' => 5),
    'fields' => 'AirtimePlaylist.id', 'AirtimePlaylist.name'
));
```

It seems however that the join between `CC_PLAYLISTCONTENTS` and `CC_FILES` is not quite playing ball. `CC_PLAYLISTCONTENTS` should join `CC_FILES` with  `CC_PLAYLISTCONTENTS`.`file_id` = `CC_FILES`.`id` but it seems to be doing `CC_PLAYLISTCONTENTS`.`id` = `CC_FILES`.`id`

AirtimePlaylist.php

```
class AirtimePlaylist extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'cc_playlist';

    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
    public $hasMany = array('AirtimePlaylistContent' => array(
        'className' => 'AirtimePlaylistContent',
        'foreignKey' => 'playlist_id'
    ));
```

AirtimePlaylistContent.php

```
class AirtimePlaylistContent extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'cc_playlistcontents';

    public $hasOne = array('AirtimePlaylist' => array(
        'className' => 'AirtimePlaylist',
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
    ),'AirtimeFile' => array(
        'className' => 'AirtimeFile',
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
    ));
```

AirtimeFile.php

```
class AirtimeFile extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'cc_files';

    public $hasMany = array('AirtimeFileAttribute' => array(
        'className' => 'AirtimeFileAttribute',
        'foreignKey' => 'track_id'
    ));
```

Comment: Replace hasOne with belongsTo for your AirtimePlaylistContent

Comment: Sadly that didn't help me at all. See below outputs of SQL Log and then the output array!


hasOne - http://pastebin.com/U1KChYFe
belongsTo - http://pastebin.com/PR8W3PyC

Comment: When you tried belongsTo - did you change the foreignkey from id to fileid for the AirtimeFile model? Also, you need to change it from id to playlist_id for the AirtimePlaylist model.